# Can't install specific version of gcc-mingw

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, gcc

I need gcc-mingw-w64 version 9.3.0 for a project to compile correctly. I am running hirsute. For this release the gcc-mingw-w64 version is 10.0 something. I already added `archive.ubuntu.org focal` to my `sources.list`. But when I run `sudo apt update`  and then `sudo apt install gcc-mingw-w64=9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 -s` the dependant packages are still installed from the hirsute repo:

```
...
    Inst binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (2.35.1-2ubuntu1+8.11 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst mingw-w64-common (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Inst mingw-w64-i686-dev (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-base (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (2.35.1-2ubuntu1+8.11 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Inst gcc-mingw-w64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
    Conf binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (2.35.1-2ubuntu1+8.11 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf mingw-w64-common (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Conf mingw-w64-i686-dev (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-base (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (2.35.1-2ubuntu1+8.11 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (8.0.0-1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32-runtime (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [amd64])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1+24.1build1 Ubuntu:21.04/hirsute [all])
    Conf gcc-mingw-w64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
    zm@pop-os:~$
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing in the right direction, but forgot two things - add *main* pocket for focal and to supply `-t=target_release` [option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/apt.8.html) to APT.

So complete solution is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main universe"
sudo apt install gcc-mingw-w64=9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 -s -t focal
```

Note: `-s` should be removed as we now have correct package origins:

> ```
> Inst libisl22 (0.22.1-1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (2.34-5ubuntu1+8.8 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (2.34-5ubuntu1+8.8 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst mingw-w64-common (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Inst mingw-w64-i686-dev (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Inst gcc-mingw-w64-base (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Inst gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Inst gcc-mingw-w64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Conf libisl22 (0.22.1-1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (2.34-5ubuntu1+8.8 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (2.34-5ubuntu1+8.8 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf mingw-w64-common (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Conf mingw-w64-i686-dev (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Conf gcc-mingw-w64-base (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (7.0.0-2 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> Conf gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64])
> Conf gcc-mingw-w64 (9.3.0-7ubuntu1+22~exp1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [all])
> ```

Comment: Thanks dude, saved my day.